# I get a query string as return value from LINQ to SQL and WCF Services and no concrete value

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, linq

i have one stupid problem and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I work with Silverlight and Visual Studio 2010. To connect to a database i used
LINQ to SQL. So far so good. Everything works fine, but at the end the result i get is
a query string and no value.

My code in the WCF Service file:

```
public string get_info()
{
    LinqMapInfoDataContext context = new LinqMapInfoDataContext();
    var result = from x in context.mytabel
                 where (x.map_x == 4) && (x.map_y == 7)
                 select x.id;
    string returnValue = result.ToString();
    return returnValue;
}
```

and my code in mainpage.xaml.cs

```
private void ser_client_get_infoCompleted(object sender, ServiceRefMapInfo.get_infoCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    lbl_key.Content = e.Result.ToString();
}
```

Well, i really thought i would get "id" (a concrete string value) shown in my browser after compiling my project, but no. lbl_key.Content shows:

```
SELECT [t0].[id] FROM [dbo].[mytable] AS [t0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
var id = result.FirstOrDefault();
string returnValue = Convert.ToString(id);
```